# Can't pass variable between C# pages ASP pages with session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, encryption

I know the answer to this will probably be something simple but I can figure it out, so I hope someone can help me.  I have inherited an old classic asp site. I have to remove the database connectionstring from the global asa file and put it in a web config and then encrypt it. My plan is to create a C# .net opening page that will read the decrypted string and then use the session to pass the string to the asp pages. I have the string decrypted and assigned to a session variable without any problems, but when the program call the asp page the session is not there.
I set the C# page to call itself and check the session id to see what happens to the session, it is reset each time to a new session. I added enableSessionState and sessionState mode to the web config and still not luck.
Does anyone have any ideas or can point me in the right direction to help solve this problem.  Thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: Unless there's a different connection string for every user, it wouldn't make sense to store the connection string in session state. That's for maintaining state for a user. If you store something in session for one user it won't be there for a different user. More likely what you want is application state. `HttpApplicationState`, `Application[key]` instead of `Session[key]`.

Comment: As Scott said, this looks like a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Doesn't makes sense storing at the session, while you can just read it again from web.config. The only explanation should be that you don't have access because it's another application, then this is why you can't pass a session between different servers.

Comment: I found what I need at this website ( http://www.nullskull.com/articles/20021207.asp) .  It give the code that allows the tranfer of session variables between ASPX pages and ASP pages. Thanks of for the help.